# Changed resources path breaks ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

When I change the path of a resource in my `routes.rb` file, ajax links stop working. Instead of loading the `.js` view, they instead load the `.html` view and then do nothing with it. Changing the route back fixes it.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround? I can specify the format: :js in the link, but that kind of defeats the purpose of unobtrusive javascript, and would then link to the js source if js was disabled.

Rails 4.0.2, ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0].

Comment: Please post the console output (via `rails s`) after navigating to the updated resource path.

Comment: Nothing seems to be out of the ordinary: https://gist.github.com/davbeck/9e442227c0f628a1e7db